# Why does curvature not cause issues in polar coordinates?

Tags: geometry, spherical-coordinates, spheres

Normally, we see spherical coordinates defined as follows: let your point $P$ lie on a circle of radius $R$ with centre at the origin $O$. Let the angles made by the projection of $OP$ onto the $xy$-plane and $OP$, with the $x$ and $z$ axis be $\phi$ and $\theta$ respectively. Then the coordinates of the point are,
$$(x,y,z)\equiv (R\sin\theta\cos\phi, R\sin\theta\sin\phi, R\cos\theta).$$

I see that sometimes we need to consider pieces of the sphere, "differential area". It is calculated by the equation,
$$\text{d}A=(R\text{ d}\theta)\cdot (R\sin\theta\text{ d}\phi)=R^2\sin\theta\text{ d}\phi.$$
The idea is that a rectangle with side lengths $\ell$ and $b$ has area $\ell \cdot b$ and we can approximate the differential area as a perfect rectangle with second order deviations (that do not matter as we take smaller and smaller pieces). However, I have been skeptic with this reasoning, because it can be deceptive. Some examples where there are holes in the geometric reasoning and that lead to incorrect conclusions are discussed in a 3b1b video titled "How to lie using visual proofs".

I want to know why this deduction can safely be made. In particular the main issue that comes to my mind is that the formula $\ell\cdot b$ assumes that the side lengths are perpendicular to each other.  If we see the differential area from "top view" (*don't* neglect the curvature), the correct direction to go seems to be perpendicular to the motion of $\hat{\theta}$ (specifically to the line segment formed due to $\theta\to\theta+\text{d}\theta$) and not along $\hat{\phi}$. Initially I thought the difference might only be apparent because my solid geometry skills are arguably not great; however, there is an essential difference: successive addition of $\text{d}\hat{\phi}$ traces a latitude. But movement in " the perpendicular direction" traces a great circle! I would be grateful if anybody could resolve the apparent disparity.

[note: some errors due to negligence were corrected]

Comment: The normal vectors for the planes of rotation associated with $\theta$ and $\phi$  are perpendicular to each other.

Comment: Yes, if you think of the rectangle as two lines then the corresponding vectors are perpendicular. I asked why doesn't the curvature affect the result. In case the perpendicular explanation is the best we can do, I suppose I would leave the question open as a reference...

Comment: Oh I get it, I have written the main issue as perpendicularity so you told me that in fact the vectors are perpendicular in space. I meant to say that if you only looked at points on the sphere and focus on the resulting geometry, the angles thus observed are not right. Except one can project the outward bulging area onto a flat plane and then the new projected area matches that of the rectangle. Hmm

Comment: I wouldn't say that the curvature is irrelevant, just that it's accounted for in the special case. Spheres play a central role in how we choose to define curvature in the first place.

Comment: Your definition of spherical coordinates is wrong. $\phi$ is *not* the angle between $\overline {OP}$ and the $x$-axis. It is the angle between *the projection of $\overline {OP}$ onto the $xy$-plane* and the positive $x$-axis. (I also far more commonly see $\theta$ and $\phi$ having the opposite roles than you;ve assigned, but that is a matter of preference.)

Comment: What you are describing as a "deduction" is what we mathematicians refer to as an "intuition". It is not rigorous in general, and is not how we actually deduce that $dA = R^2\sin \theta\,d\theta\,d\phi$. For that we have the much more rigorously developed concept of the Jacobian.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Sorry, I was sloppy while writing the question. I have *not* encountered any use of spherical coordinates in a purely mathematical context but rather in electrostatics and the like. Then I saw three authors defining spherical coordinates in three different ways [like switching roles of $\theta$ and $\phi$, as you mentioned]. In those places, they directly wrote the "formula" for the differential area, as is typical of pre-college calculus [although $\rm{d/d}$$x$ is an operator, they ask us to think in terms of changes]. I would be obliged if you can provide a good reference.